# What is the social history of British popular opposition to Thatcher over the miner’s strike?

Tags: united-kingdom, social-history, modern, labour-history, political-economy

I tend to watch a lot of UK panel shows and while most of the comedians are Labour/liberal I'm still surprised at just how much they seem to hate Margaret Thatcher. Particularly this seems to be about the way she handled the Miner's strike in 1984.

What is the social history of popular disagreement with Thatcher's policies on mines and her handling of the Miner's strike and it's aftermath?

Comment: +1 Interesting to me as an Asian. Back then Thatcher looked like an Iron Woman The Strong to me.

Comment: @SamuelRussell I'm happy for any suggestions for removing any political bias from the question. I'm sure I'm more Tory than Labour coming from a country who spent 40 years under communist rule, and personally being much better off under the capitalist (right wing) regime, but this was not meant to be a confirmation bait question.

Comment: I’ve stripped the closed ended bias, and given your real question which is the social reason for continued disagreement with a policy from the 1980s

Comment: @DRF - Welcome to the site. Closer to original question, miners were symbolic of Thatcher's policies to dismantle unions. See [**Battle of Orgreave**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Orgreave) on the brutality of Police in disrupting strikes. **Even after 30 years (2015), there were still calls for an independent inquiry in police misconduct. That should give an idea of how badly miners were treated then.** Not sure if this little info fits an answer. Hence, made as comment.

Comment: I can't help but wonder whether the "popular disagreement" is coming from a small (but vocal) segment of the population.  After all, she did manage to remain Prime Minister for more than a decade. which certainly suggests that the majority of voters preferred Conservative policies to the Labour alternatives.

Comment: @jamesqf Maybe not small, but surely minoritary. In any case, the Falklands war did wonders for her. According to polls, she wouldn't had been re-elected without that conflict.

Comment: Having spoken with a number of Brits who lived in Britain during the Thatcher years the impression I got was the hatred towards Thatcher & her government was due to the sense of abandonment they felt after the mines were forced to close. Apparently very little, if any, attempt was made by the Thatcher government to provide alternate forms of employment or to maintain society within the affected communities. The closes were the result of hard uncompromising economic policies that results in the affected masses having to fend for themselves in the aftermath.

Comment: In 1973 a miners' strike had led to the bringing down of Edward Heath's  Conservative government. The latter had called a General Election using the mantra "Who governs Britain?", the implication being that unions were usurping the government's role. The elctorate answered - by a very small margin "Not you mate" - and Labour took over under Harold Wilson. This caused fury among Conservatives and many agree that the miners' strike of 1984 was provoked by the Thatcher government as a punishment for what the miners had done 11 years earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*edit: originally this question asked specifically about modern comedians, and that's what I've tried to answer below*.

The UK comedy scene, once called 'alternative comedy' started as an anti-Thatcher subculture in urban comedy clubs. 'Thatcher, eh?' used to be a lazy go-to line for a comedian to show he was 'one of us'.

Before that, UK comedy generally depended on super inoffensive 'mother in law jokes', or blatant racism at the other extreme. So be grateful!

By mil jokes, I mean jokes so bland (and usually unfunny) that you wouldn't mind telling them to your prudish mil, not jokes *about* her.

The above being said;

- There was a great deal of police brutality, particularly by the Met.
- There was little attempt to provide alternative employment in the old coal areas. Many miners have remained unemployed to this day.
- The ex-mining areas, generally up north or in the other home nations, have remained economically depressed for the subsequent generations.
- More broadly, Thatcher is the figurehead of the philosophies which degraded our public services, and fostered horrendous inequality.

Comment: ' ... _particularly by the Met_'?  I hadn't realised that there was a great deal of coal mining in the Metropolitan Police jurisdiction (Greater London).

Comment: There isn't. Thatcher sent police from all over the country to the striking areas. She felt that local police would be too soft on their own community!

Comment: I know. I also know that command of policing remained with the regions, so those officers were temporarily attached to those forces.  Which is why you may want to cite some evidence to support your claim that the 'police brutality' was _particularly by the Met_.

Comment: That observation is based on conversations I have had with police officers who were involved in policing the strike. No one's obliged to take it at face value, but personal experiences have long been considered an acceptable kind of source here. Everything else I said I'm too lazy to source, but can be trivially looked up on Wikipedia.

Comment: Interesting. Most of the conversations I've had with police officers who were sent to police the strike centred around the fact that they weren't properly trained to deal with the levels of violence they were facing, & that they were usually standing next to officers from elsewhere in the country who had even less training! (I've also heard that they often had to restrain those officers when their 'blood was up'). Of course, it may make sense that police who had to rebuild relations with local communities after the strike would blame 'outsiders', and the Met would be an easy target for that.

Comment: Er, looking at the edit history of the question, the only reference to comedians from the original is still there.

Comment: The original title was *Why is Thatcher so often attacked for the way she handled the miner's strike*. The body only mentioned attacks by comedians.

Comment: I didn’t intend to edit the question out from under you, but the non-historical portions of the original question indicated an interest in Thatchers broader reception, as well as comedians. I think this is still a great answer even to the edited version.

Comment: No problem at all, I just wanted my answer to be clear :)

Comment: Ne Mo offensive Mother-In-law jokes about her were a mainstay of the comedy scene back then particularly Les Dawson and Ken Dodds.